# Compact operator

Tags: functional-analysis, compact-operators

Please, help with the problem. Is the Hilbert operator, which defined by matrix $ \{ a_{i,j} = \frac{1}{i+j} \}^{\infty}_{i,j=1}$ , compact on space $l_2$ ?

I will add my thoughts about the problem as soon as I formulate and issue them

I think that it can be proved that Hilbert operator is bounded on $L_2 (\mathbb{N}, 2^{ \mathbb{N} }, \#)$, where $\#$ is the counting measure, and that  the embedding operator $Jx=x$ from $L_2 (\mathbb{N}, 2^{ \mathbb{N} }, \#)$ to $l_{2}$ is compact. It will mean that the Hilbert operator is compact as the composition of compact and bounded operators

Comment: Hi! I want to remind you that it is generally preferred you include context when asking a question here (which can include: where this problem came from, your own attempts, and a *specific* idea as to where you're stuck) - it also lets us help you better! As is, your question is little more than an isolated problem, and thus likely to get a lot of downvotes and closed. Feel free to [edit] the context into your post though! Here's a useful link: [asking a good question](https://goo.gl/11Cojp).

Comment: This is not a jukebox for requesting solutions. If you're stuck on something, people can help. What have you tried?

Comment: The fact that the kernel of the operator $T\phi(j)=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{j+k}\phi(k)$, that is $\\Phi(j,k)=\frac{1}{k+j}$ is not in $\ell_2(\mathbb{N}\times\mathbb{N})$ may be an indication that the operator is not compact. This is not always the case though, but it is a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to prove on your own the continuity of the operator  $T\phi(j)=\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{j+k}\phi(k)$ on $\ell_2(\mathbb{N})$. As for compactness, this is from a paper by [Barria and Halmos](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1982-273-02/S0002-9947-1982-0667164-X/S0002-9947-1982-0667164-X.pdf). Consider the sequence $\phi_n(j)=\frac{1}{n}\mathbb{1}_{\{1,\ldots,n^2\}}(j)$. This is a unit-norm sequence in $\ell_2$.

- Check that for any $\phi\in\ell_2$, $\langle\phi_n,\phi\rangle=\sum^\infty_{j=1}\phi_n(j)\phi(j)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$. This means that $\phi_n$ converges weakly to $0$ in $\ell_2$.
- Check that $\langle\phi_n,T\phi_n\rangle\geq\frac12$.
- From this, deduce that $T$ cannot be compact, for if $T\phi_{n_k}\rightarrow\phi\in\ell_2$, then 
  \begin{align}
  \frac12\leq\langle\phi_{n_k},T\phi_{n_k}\rangle &= \langle\phi_{n_k},T\phi_{n_k}-\phi\rangle +\langle\phi_{n_k},\phi\rangle\\
  &\leq \|T\phi_{n_k}-\phi\|_2+\langle\phi_{n_k},\phi\rangle\xrightarrow{k\rightarrow\infty}0
  \end{align}
  which is absurd.